# Dynamic button and getTag in click method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create dynamic buttons and add click functionality in them. I tried to getTag method in elements of button array. Whenever i try to run these codes app crashes i tried both i.e. v.getTag() and button.getTag(). Thank you for helping me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testing);
        //test creating of dynamic buttons
         Button[] myButton = new Button[4];
        LinearLayout scrViewButLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
            myButton[index] = new Button(this); //initialize the button here
            myButton[index].setText("Button # ");
            myButton[index].setTag(index);
            scrViewButLay.addView(myButton[index]);
          myButton[index].setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(myButton[index]));
        }
    }


  View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setText("text now set.. ");
                //Log.i("info",(String) button.getTag());
                Log.i("info",(String) v.getTag());
            }

        }; 
   }
}
```

LogCat Error-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
com.example.mandeep.pos1_1, PID: 26112
                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                                                at com.example.mandeep.pos1_1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: Try setting id for your buttons

Comment: what error did you get? can you post the stack trace?

Comment: post logcat here

Comment: add this in your code

Comment: post it with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
Log.i("info", ""+v.getTag());
```

or if you want to parse it into int.

```
final int tag = Integer.parseInt(""+v.getTag());
```